# python urllib alternative to requests.put command?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, urllib

I want to send image data via urllib python 3.6 library.
i presently have an implementation of a python 2.7 with the help of requests  library.

Id there a way to replace the requests lib with the urllib in this code.

```
import argparse
import io
import os
import sys
import base64
import requests


def read_file_bytestream(image_path):
    data = open(image_path, 'rb').read()
    return data


if __name__== "__main__":
    data=read_file_bytestream("testimg.png")
    requests.put("http.//0.0.0.0:8080", files={'image': data})
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way, pretty much taken from the docs:

```
import urllib.request

def read_file_bytestream(image_path):
    data = open(image_path, 'rb').read()
    return data

DATA = read_file_bytestream("file.jpg")
req = urllib.request.Request(url='http://httpbin.org/put', data=DATA, method='PUT')
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
    pass
print(f.status)
print(f.reason)
```

Comment: It should work in theory, but somehow I'm uploading empty files (size 0) under the correct file name. I wonder if anyone faced the same issue.

Comment: @hoohoo-b File permissions?